# efficient way to find all matches and none matches comparing one array to another

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, knockout.js

I am working on a list system with a tagging system using knockoutJS.

There is a central list of 'items' - each with its own set of tags (0, 1 or more tags)

The idea is to have multiple lists with different tags and then display any matches.

For example:-

```
item 1 - tags 1,3
item 2 - tags 2,4
item 3 - tags 4
item 4 - tags NONE
```

and

```
List 1 - tags 1,2
List 2 - tags 3
```

Plus 2 extra lists generated by the system, one for 'no tags' and one for 'no lists' (to pick up items with no tags and items which do not match a list respectively).

This would result in:-

```
List NO TAGS = item 4
List NO LIST = item 3
List 1       = item 1, item 2
List 2       = item 1
```

The problem I am having is an efficient way to sort the items into the lists as at the moment I am running multiple loops and resetting the items held in each list each time a change is made.

The below code is ugly I know, it is more for reference, I suppose the question is what is the most efficient way to compare tags in the data structure shown at the bottom

**UGLY WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
ko.computed(function () {
//clear all items in arrays
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.lists(), function (list) {
    list.items([]);
});
var onList; //does this item appear on a list yet
//loop through all items and then all lists to see if an item matches any tags on that list and if so add it.
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function (item) {
    onList = 0; //reset whether found - used for adding to 'No List'
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.lists(), function (list) {


            //if an item has no tasks then add to list id - 2 'No Tags' List
            if (item.tags().length == 0 && list.id() == -2) {
                list.items.push(item);
                onList = 1; //found a list
            } else {
                //now for each item loop through tags and then loop through lists tags and find any matches
                ko.utils.arrayFirst(item.tags(), function (tag) {
                    var found = 0;

                    ko.utils.arrayFirst(list.tags(), function (listTag) {

                        console.log(listTag, tag);
                        if (parseInt(listTag) == parseInt(tag)) {
                            list.items.push(item);
                            found = 1;
                            onList = 1;
                            //at least one tag matches, so exit
                            return 1;
                        }
                    });

                    if (found == 1) {
                        //at least one tag matches, so exit 
                        return 1;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //there were no matches in any of the lists so add this to the list 'No List'
        if(onList == 0 && self.lists().length > 1){
                self.lists()[1].items.push(item);
        }

    });
});
```

**DATA STRUCTURE**

```
///4 lists - the first 2 are system generated 'catch' lists
var listData = [
    {id: -2, name: "NO TAGS", tags: [
           //NOT APPLICABLE AS HANDLED BY CODE
        ]
    },
    {id: -1, name: "NO LIST", tags: [
           //NOT APPLICABLE AS HANDLED BY CODE
        ]
    },
    {id: 1, name: "List 1", tags: [
            2
        ]
    },
    {id: 2, name: "List 2", tags: [
            1, 3
        ]
    }
];

//2 sets of items
var itemData = [
    {id: 1, name: "Item 1", addedBy: 1, tags: [
            1
        ]},
    {id: 2, name: "Item 2", addedBy: 1, tags: [
            2, 3
        ]}
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not got a definite answer and I wonder if you might get more responses on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but I enjoyed having a bit of a think about your question.

This is a bit long for a comment, but not quite an answer. Hope it is useful anyway.

I don't think your approach is too bad - as an imperative block of code to solve the problem, it does the job in the obvious manner. You could perhaps speed up calculating the intersection of list.tags() and item.tags() by preprocessing one of them into a hash. But you make good use of arrayFirst to exit both loops as soon as a match is found.

Modern JS&browsers will probably crunch through this for large lists in no time at all. The issue, especially with KO, will probably arise with rendering your lists in the browser. Have you noticed performance problems already or are you wondering about this issue from a more academic point of view?

If you have already seen performance problems, this will be because KO is fairly slow at creating things in the DOM - a list of 1000 items takes a noticeable to render compared with creating an HTML string for those 1000 items and then inserting it into the DOM in one go using a container's innerHTML property. This is especially true if you add items to a list one by one, as you do in your code with

```
list.items.push(item);
```

and

```
self.lists()[1].items.push(item);
```

The problem with this is explained in a useful blog post here:

http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

That blog post recommends setting your observableArrays in one go, so within that approach your code that clears each list, then repopulates it, will be fine, so long as you rewrite it slightly to stores your matches in a temporary array, then put them in the observable in one go.

Another thing to watch out for is that you have 4 lists and even if you do the above, you'll generate 4 notifications to redraw the UI as each list gets populated. You could work around this by making use of deferred updates:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html

Your algorithm takes the approach of building each list by looping over the lists then the items and working out if the item belongs in the given list. An alternative that would not destroy the list is loop over the items and then the lists, and for each item work out if it needs to add or remove itself from a list. Algorithmically you still need to loop al the items and all the lists and within that compute the intersection of the list filter and the item tags so I don't think it makes things better there. And from KO's point of view, each time you add or remove an item from a list, you still change the observableArray, so I don't think it would be faster there, either.

KO tends to promote a functional style of programming and I suppose from that point of view it could be argued that your code is ugly, though I think you are being too harsh on yourself! Using a functional style allows your list matches to be generated from ko.computed functions. You don't have to explicitly empty each list each time something changes. Possibly this enables KO's dependency tracking to do something clever when a list does not change in terms of not re-rendering the DOM? As an example of this, I wrote this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/325gp71a/3/

Some things it does:

**Make use of deferUpdates**

```
// Using deferUpdates=true will help performance when altering the lists.
//   - When true, all lists will be recalculated before UI redrawing
//   - When false, as each list changes the UI will redraw
// In my browser ,the time taken to add lots of items when clicking the test
// button is:
//   - deferUpdates=false takes approx 10 seconds
//   - deferUpdated=true takes approx 4 seconds
//
ko.options.deferUpdates = true;
```

**Make use of that hash I mentioned above to make the tag/filter intersection a bit faster:**

```
// Reduce the filter to a hash to remove one loop from the matching process.
// The filter [2,3] will become the hash {2: true, 3: true}
this.hash = {}
ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.filter, function(f) {
    this.hash[f] = true
}.bind(this))

....skip a bit of code, then....

match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(tags, function(tag) {
    return this.hash.hasOwnProperty(tag)
}.bind(this))
```

**Ensure the observableArrays are set in just one go rather than adding items one-by-one to an observableArray:**

For the items:

```
    // Once all the new items are ready, put them into the observableArray
    // on one go.
    new_items = this.items().concat(new_items)
    this.items(new_items)
```

For the list matches, this is done through it being in a ko.computed. Therefore if this list has not changed, the value of the computed should not change, and KO will not have to re-render this bit of the DOM:

```
// Find the matches for this list.
this.matches = ko.computed(function() {
    var matches = []

    ... do the logic ...

    // Done.
    return matches
}, this)
```

Finally, I added a couple of test buttons to evaluate performance. One button adds a 1000 items with various random tags, and on my browser that takes 4 seconds, which I am pretty sure is entirely down to KO manipulating the DOM. `deferUpdates=true` helps here; without it, it takes around 10 seconds. This is because deferUpdates ensures all the computeds are evaluated before drawing the DOM; without it the DOM is redrawn more frequently.

The other test modifies one of the items, and this is redrawn from one list to the other pretty quickly - the change appears to be instant in my browser. Each computed is re-evaluated by this change, but KO's dependency tracking seems to be able to redraw the difference without redrawing the entire list, making it fast.

Comment: Probably the best way to make the code work faster is use `deferUpdates=true`

Comment: I've only just upgraded my projects to KO3.4 and most of the reason I got interested in this question was to learn about deferUpdates for myself. Today's job is to try it out in my app.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response, deferred updates are already on and I have taken your points on-board and am going to work on them this weekend. I just wondered if I was missing some obvious algorithm but I think with your points I can make it lean enough to start off with and address speed later, I just didn't want to have to rewrite the thing with a different structure later. +1 and I will accept so you get a few points :-)

Comment: Also the reason I was looking for a more efficient route was because there may be 20 lists with 5 tags average and 200 items each with 5 tags on average - by my calculations that is going to be approx 25000 loops on average (and 100000 in a worst case scenario) so your hash helps reduce that slightly. I will see what I can come up with!!! Once again thanks

Comment: My guess is that rendering will remain more of a bottleneck than the algorithm and hence you will be bound by the number of lists and number of items, rather than the time taken to arrange the items into their lists. As a quick test I tweaked my fiddle and reduced the 'add items' button to add just 200 items, but this time each one has up to 5 tags, each tag being in the range 1-20. I created 10 lists with 5 tags each. In my browser this is still rendering in 4-5 seconds, so I reckon the increase in list & tags count has been offset by the reduction in item count and it is still performant.

Comment: New fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/325gp71a/4/ ... Good luck over the weekend! and thanks for the accept+points - always welcome :-)